# Parse signed number from string

Tags: java, regex, parsing, regular-language

I have string like:

```
"-------5548481818fgh7hf8ghf----fgh54f4578"
```

I don't want to parse using Pattern and Matcher. I have code:

```
string.replaceAll("regex", ""));
```

How to make `regex` to exclude all symbols except a "-" to get string like:

```
-554848181878544578
```

Comment: this is simple..what have you tried

Comment: How did you get from `-------5548481818fgh7hf8ghf----fgh54f4578`  to `-554848181878544578`?

Comment: @Pillar I have updated the post

Comment: side note... could you improve the english? I found this difficult to read as a native speaker. What does "I don't want to parse using Pattern and Matcher" mean? and really? "I have code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
String s = "-------5548481818fgh7hf8ghf----fgh54f4578";

String r = s.replaceAll("(?!^[-+])\\D+", "");
//=> -554848181878544578
```

`(?!^-)\D` will replace each non-digit except the hyphen at start.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP5zU6/2)

Comment: Good idea, added it. Not sure why it was downvoted though.

Comment: yeah, all the three answers..seems like someone is offended

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
String Str = new String("-------5548481818fgh7hf8ghf----fgh54f4578-");
String tmp = Str.replaceAll("([-+])+|([^\\d])","$1").replaceAll("\\d[+-](\\d|$)","");
System.out.println(tmp);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/zRJccM)**

Comment: who the hell is downvoting?

Comment: Case of serial downvoting I think

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: Grab the opposite, instead of replacing the negative. Seems to be arbitrary that you've picked to remove characters you don't want, instead of grabbing the characters you **do** want. Example in javascript:

```
s = "-------5548481818fgh7hf8ghf----fgh54f4578"
s = '-' + s.match(/[0-9]+/g).join('')
// "-554848181878544578"
```